# Is it possible to associate a given language with a file extension in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it currently possible to associate a given language with a file extension that is not typically associated with that language?

Say I have a filetype *.foo, and I want to associate it with JavaScript for syntax highlighting. Does anyone know if this is currently possible with VSCode?

I am working in a language that is syntactically similar to Visual Basic, and want to associate it with that language type. I understand that you can assign a language after the file is opened, however this is cumbersome to do each time a file is opened.

In Sublime Text for example it is possible to select "Open all with current extension as...". Does this exist yet for VSCode?

EDIT: The Visual Studio Code team has added a proper way to add both themes and languages.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_yo-code-streamlined-customizations-for-vs-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an update to the answer of this question, so I wanted to update it.

The Visual Studio Code team released a proper way to add new Languages and Themes to the application using a Yeoman generator with TextMate tmBundles which is documented here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_yo-code-streamlined-customizations-for-vs-code

and here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_customization-adding-language-colorization-bracket-matching

Answer (score 17):

VSCode v1.0 officially adds the File to Language Association feature. Add the following into `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.foo": "javascript"
}
```

You may find more details in the [Visual Studio Code 1.0.0 release notes “File to language association” section](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vMarch#_editor).

Comment: You may need to restart VSCode after changing the setting.

Comment: Is anyone able to find a page in the documentation that lists all the names of the supported language?  For example: C++ is supported, but do I put "c++" in the file, or "cpp" or something else?  I can only find the example with "php".

Answer (score 6):

You can do it yourself:
For this example I'll add the ".ino" files to the C++ plugin.

Navigate to the folder containing the corresponding plugin:
**C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.0\resources\app\plugins\vs.language.cpp**

Open the **ticino.plugin.json** file and edit **contributes.language.extension**. In this case, you go from:

```
"extensions": [ ".cpp", ".c", ".cc", ".cxx", ".h", ".hpp", ".hh"],
```

to

```
"extensions": [ ".cpp", ".c", ".cc", ".cxx", ".h", ".hpp", ".hh", ".ino" ],
```

Comment: Let's say we wanted to open twig or smarty files as HTML......I don't see a corresponding folder for HTML and I don't see anywhere else it might be.

Comment: There are other files that may be useful in **\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.0\resources\app\client\vs\languages**

Comment: Thanks @Sargeros. Worth mentioning on the MacOS side it can be found here:
`/Volumes/Mac OS/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins/vs.language.vb`

Comment: I have the same issue as @patricksweeney above; I can't see how to do this for html...

Comment: @mutex I guess you could edit **\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.3.0\resources\app\plugins\vs.language.xml\ticino.plugin.json** and add the extension you want. If it can highlight XML it should be able to do the same for HTML.

Comment: @Sargeros: Thanks for the idea. I asked another question on this and got a decent workaround for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656126/visual-studio-code-treat-other-extensions-as-html

Looks like it's on the roadmap too :)

Comment: I see no **ticino.plugin.json** file under **vs.language.javascript**
There is only **snippets** directory

Comment: Will these changes carry between versions?

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: The above answer didn't work for me (strange) - but I reworked it to the following]

Open the file

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.3\resources\app\client\vs\workbench\workbench.main.js
```

replace

```
t.knownTextMimes={
```

with

```
t.knownTextMimes={".twig":"text/html",
```

---

We're simply adding the mime-type to the array of known text mimes.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think you are addressing a different question. The solution above still works in current versions of the VSCode.

Comment: Strange, I couldn't get the above working on my work or home PC - so I re-worked it. Thanks for informing me!

Answer (score -2):

- Go to ***File*** > ***Preferences*** > ***Settings***
- In the right tree-view, expand *Text **Editor*** and choose ***Files***
- In the ***Associations*** section click ***Edit in settings.json***

In the right editor, you can add your associations. Here is a sample that adds the extension `.hpp`

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "c++ header files": ".hpp"
  }
}
```

Comment: The object content is inverted, it is `pattern` as attribute and `language` as value, e.g.`"*.ext": "somelanguage"`