# Scala with VScode

Tags: scala, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

I started to use vscode for python development. And I really like it, does anyone know how to extend VScode so I can write scala in it as well ?

At the bare minimum I need to get syntax highlighting working.

Comment: Hii, I also tried VSCode for django development, do you know how to exclude .pyc file on file explorer?.

Comment: there is another stack overflow question with the vscode tag which shows how to associate a file type with a language but basically you change some json afaik

Comment: @ChromableedStudios I'll take a look thanks. If you happen to have the url it would be super helpful :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956304/is-it-possible-to-associate-a-given-language-with-a-file-extention-in-vscode

Answer (score 12):

Scala works well in VS Code 2019.

There's official [syntax highlighting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=scala-lang.scala), and a Language Server called [Metals](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=scalameta.metals) (which replaces Ensime which is mentioned in other answers).

Comment: What is a Language Server?

Language Server is a special kind of Visual Studio Code extension that powers the editing experience for many programming languages. With Language Servers, you can implement autocomplete, error-checking (diagnostics), jump-to-definition, and many other language features supported in VS Code.

Answer (score 9):

There is one here:

https://github.com/IliyaTryapitsin/vscode-scala

You can add it by reading the readme there which is:

Run VSCode

```
code --enableExtensionGallery
```

Press F1 then input:

for scala installation

```
ext install scala
```

for sbt installation

```
ext install sbt
```

for snippets installation

```
ext install scalasnippets
```

Answer (score 4):

If your NOT using Intellij or Eclipse and want to stick to VSCode, then I highly recommend Ensime & Ensime plugin below:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dragos.scala-lsp
Also check out, www.ensime.org
It's a bit more involved to setup ensime env but still worth it.

Discussion of two is below here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/5eu9if/intellij_vs_ensime/

However, Intellij has improved a lot. So, the beauty contest is a matter of judgement call.
I have been switch back & forth between many variations (Emacs, Intellij, neovim, VSCode). It's a complicated language. So, I need all the help I can get!

Comment: I will add that ensime is only real deal when it comes to helpfulness on the VSCode side, especially compared to IntelliJ. I wish VSCode was good as IntelliJ natively or with a single plugin as ensime is really NOT easy to setup at 1st.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig into the applications path it looks to me to be extensible in .js, take a look at the javascript and typescript folders for example(though I haven't tried it yet)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code does not have a language extensible story yet, but it could be coming soon. 
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages#_common-questions

Answer (score 1):

[scala](https://github.com/scala) has official [vs code scala extension](https://github.com/scala/vscode-scala-syntax)