# Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code recognize HTML syntax in EJS files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on a Mac to work on Node.js applications.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code recognize EJS files as HTML markup?  I didn't see any file / scheme association in user preferences.

Comment: Annoyingly this appears to do just what you (and I) need, but there is no corresponding folder for HTML:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956304/is-it-possible-to-associate-a-given-language-with-a-file-extention-in-vscode

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Actually, you can.

As Andre points out, now you can do this in the workspace settings.Go to Visual Studio Code Settings: `File >> Preferences >> User Settings`

```js
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{                
// Configure file associations to languages (e.g. "*.extension": "html"). These have precedence over the default associations of the languages installed.
     "files.associations": {"*.ejs": "html"}     
 }
```

Click on the 'Plain text' tab at the bottom of the VS Code window and change it to `HTML`, screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make this default? I mean, this works for one file. When I open other .ejs files, it still consider them as plain text.

Comment: @Kurotsuki check my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264197/is-there-a-way-to-make-visual-studio-code-recognize-html-syntax-in-ejs-files#comment-55381824 on how to permanently treat .ejs as html language mode.

Comment: There is now an extension to support .ejs syntax highlighting, see the answer by @pablovilas

Comment: With the most recent versions, when you click on the Plain Text tab at the bottom, you now get an option to "Configure file association for ..." which will let you set the default for this file type.

Comment: nice, and fast :)

Answer (score 64):

Go to Visual Studio Code Settings. 
File >> Preferences >> User Settings

Add this line in the settings.json.

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{                
    // Configure file associations to languages (e.g. "*.extension": "html"). These have precedence over the default associations of the languages installed.
    "files.associations": {"*.ejs": "html"}     
}
```

Restart Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Easiest solution!

Comment: but don't we loose ejs (javascript) syntax in ejs htmlized files ?

Comment: There is now an extension to support .ejs syntax highlighting, see the answer by @pablovilas

Comment: You may also need to close and re-open the file.

Answer (score 29):

There is an extension for .ejs support. Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and type enter.

```
ext install ejs-language-support
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work with the VSCode version I'm using (1.6)

Comment: this should be marked as the best answer now.  works fine as of v1.7

Comment: This plugin actually removes syntax highlighting for HTML code. I don't link it!

Comment: @Sinandro it does not for me. Perhaps you have a conflicting extension. ejs-language-support@0.0.1 still works on vscode 1.73 - I guess it is both feature complete and extremely stable!

Answer (score 21):

Following the directions given by [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/colorizer)
I changed this file c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\package.json 
so it looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "html",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "publisher": "vscode",
    "engines": { "vscode": "*" },
    "extensionDependencies": [
                     "html"
                ],
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [{
            "id": "html",
            "aliases": ["ejs"],
            "extensions": [".ejs"]
        }]
    }
}
```

tried..works for me..too lazy to create a new folder atm

Comment: I am using Mac OSX and this worked for me too. I went to `/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/html/package.json` . You can copy+paste the path to your Finder -> Go To Folder. What I actually is to go to Applications folder, right click Visual Studio Code then Show Package Content

Comment: This solution worked for me, but it is not the optimal solution as we will have to perform the change again after an update to that extension.

Answer (score 6):

Locate the `html` extension in VSCode `extensions` folder:

`../app/extensions/html`

that on MacOS X is

`/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/html`

and on Windows is

`c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\package.json`

Now edit the file `package.json` adding `.ejs` the `extensions` array only:

```
{
        "name": "html",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "publisher": "vscode",
        "engines": { "vscode": "*" },
        "contributes": {
                "languages": [{
                        "id": "html",
                        "extensions": [ ".html", ".htm", ".shtml", ".mdoc", ".jsp", ".asp", ".aspx", ".jshtm", ".ejs" ],
                        "aliases": [ "HTML", "htm", "html", "xhtml" ],
                        "mimetypes": ["text/html", "text/x-jshtm", "text/template", "text/ng-template"]
                }],
                "grammars": [{
                        /* "language": "html", not yet enabled*/
                        "scopeName": "text.html.basic",
                        "path": "./syntaxes/HTML.plist"
                }]
        }

}
```

By the way, the correct way should be to create a `ejs` `extension` in the `extensions` folder and then adding:

```
ejs/
ejs/package.json
ejs/snippet/
ejs/snippet/ejs.json
ejs/syntaxes/
ejs/syntaxes/EJS.plist
```

Of course this should have the EJS syntax / grammar, but we can simply duplicate the html one, so from the extensions folder:

```
cd html/
cp -r * ../ejs/
```

The `package.json` then could be like

```
{
        "name": "ejs",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "publisher": "vscode",
        "engines": { "vscode": "*" },
        "contributes": {
                "languages": [{
                        "id": "ejs",
                        "extensions": [ ".ejs" ],
                        "aliases": [ "EJS", "ejs" ],
                        "mimetypes": ["text/html", "text/x-jshtm", "text/template", "text/ng-template"]
                }],
                "grammars": [{
                        "scopeName": "text.html.basic",
                        "path": "./syntaxes/EJS.plist"
                }]
        }

}
```

so change `syntaxes/HTML.plist` just copied to `syntaxes/EJS.plist`.

Then restart VSCode.

Comment: There is now an extension to support .ejs syntax highlighting, see the answer by @pablovilas

Comment: The language extension did nothing for me, even after reloading.

Answer (score 1):

The new release, allow us add textmate snippets: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_add-textmate-snippets 
maybe we can add this one for ejs support: 
https://github.com/gregory-m/ejs-tmbundle/blob/master/Syntaxes/JavaScript%20Template.tmLanguage

Comment: While these links may be related to the question, it's always better to include important parts of answer here and then add a link of reference. Link-only answers become invalid when the linked-pages change over time.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 Community I was able to associate the ejs extension with the html editor:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension

Enter "ejs" in the extension.  Pick "HTML Editor" from the dropdown selection.  Click Add.  Click OK.

If you have an ejs file open, close it and reopen.

Comment: The question mentions VS Code, not Visual Studio. VS Code doesn't have any Tools menu.

Comment: Stumbled into this question while looking for this option in Visual Studio. Thank you BDH.

Comment: marry me. been looking for this for hours