# How to clear error when writing EJS in html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ejs

I'm using vue cli 3 to generate a new project. My IDE is VSCode. It's OK to write `<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>` in `./public/index.html`. 
Now I write

```
    <script>
        window.GetVersion = function () {
            return {
              v: <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.version %>,
            };
        };
    </script>
```

in `./public/index.html` too. **The function works well**. but the VSCode shows some error like this: 
[image]

BTW, the `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.version` returns a NUMBER, and it will be no error to change to

```
v: Number('<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.version %>'),
```

I just want to know, is there a way to fix those error without changing the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Extensions` section on Vscode and search `qassimfarid.ejs-language-support` and install it. After installation, close Vscode and then re-open it.

If you don't like installing extensions but you want some configurations to be done, click below link.

- [Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code recognize HTML syntax in EJS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264197/is-there-a-way-to-make-visual-studio-code-recognize-html-syntax-in-ejs-files#comment-55381824)

Comment: As I said, this will works but this will change `Number` to `String`, I have to warp this with `Number(...)` or something. Just don't want to do this and wondered another way.