# File associations in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know is it possible to set file associations in vscode?

I'm working with .pt files which contain html and was looking to set the editor, so that when it opens these files it automatically set the type to html.

Comment: I believe it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956304/is-it-possible-to-associate-a-given-language-with-a-file-extention-in-vscode?rq=1 that was answered.

Answer (score 15):

<s>Currently changing a mode is not persisted on a file. For the future we will look into an option to allow the user to associate file extensions to modes and persist this setting.</s>

**Update for our VS Code 1.0 release:**

You can now persist a file to language association in settings. The newly introduced `files.associations` setting can be used like this:

```
files.associations: {
   "*.php4": "php",
   "*.php3": "php"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If switching language using the bottom-right menu is annoying you - I have an interim solution, it isn't automated but it allows keyboard-switching:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+l",
        "command": "workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
]
```

You can now type `CTRL` + `L` then `HT` then `ENTER`.

VSCode remembers what language you have selected and even remembers that language if you copy and paste files (either in VSCode or on the file system). I can't see where they have stored that information though.

So you would only need to do this for brand new files.