# Visual Studio Code: Treat other extensions as HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code

For the purposes of syntax highlighting and colouring and intellisense is it possible to treat other extensions (tpl, master, etc) as HTML?

I know it's possible on a file by file basis by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+P and selecting "Change Language Mode" BUT I want it to work off file extension, and not have to redo it every time I open a new file.

I also know it's possible for some languages by editing the json files in the plugins directory, BUT there doesn't seem to be one for HTML.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**Update for VS Code 1.0:**

There is a setting `files.associations` that can be used to assign file patterns to languages. For example:

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.tpl": "html",
  "*.master": "html"
}
```

Previous answer:

<s>This is a commonly asked feature request and we are looking into this issue for the future.</s>

As a workaround if you need to have a solutio now:

- close VS Code
- open `C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Local\Code\app-<latest-version>\resources\app\server\lib\mime.js`
- find the object literal `knownTextMimes`
- for the file extension you want add the proper mime type
- for example `'.tpl': 'text/html'`
- save and restart code

Note: this change will not survive automatic updates but the hopes are that there is a better solution in the future update :)

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly - this is definitely more than good enough as a workaround for now. I look forward to a solution that survives updates though :)

Comment: Watch progress and vote for this feature here http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7758015-mapping-code-language-to-file-extensions

Comment: i actually asked the product team at msft directly about this feature.  high priority, hopefully ( but cannot commit ) that it will hit before the end of the year.  until then, great post.

Comment: This no longer works and you should create simple extension as stated in Jesse Watson's answer.

Comment: On mac app >> preferences >> setting, search for files.associations then add the above code.

Answer (score 15):

(Tested on version 1.59.1)

It is also possible to set Associations through GUI:

Go to Settings->Text Editor->Files->Associations.

Set Item (file extension) and Value (language).

[image]

Comment: This worked for me,  I just added

ITEM COLUMN =   *.tmpl     VALUE COLUMN = html

Answer (score 2):

I resolve the issue for my with installing Smarty Extension 1.1.1 + adding this settings into Settings.json

```
"files.associations": {
"*.tpl": "smarty",
"*.master": "smarty"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open notepad as admin (just in case) by right clicking run as admin.
2. Click file => open => copy and paste C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html in box.
3. select view all file types at bottom right.
4. Open package.json
5. Copy and paste

   ```
   {
   "name": "html",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "publisher": "vscode",
   "engines": { "vscode": "*" },
   "extensionDependencies": [
                    "html"
               ],
   "contributes": {
       "languages": [{
           "id": "html",
           "aliases": ["pd"],
           "extensions": [".pd"]
       }]
     }
   }
   ```

replace everything with that.
save and quit
restart vs code.

Comment: Replace .pd with the file type you want to treat as html.  That was my bad, I use .pd.

Comment: Where would this file be found in the MacOS X installation of Code?

Comment: It should, I believe, be in the same area.  I do not use Mac but the file structure should be similar.  The file you are looking for on a windows machine is hidden.  Meaning you have to select view all files in folder option to see it.  So keep that in mind when you are looking for it.

Comment: ubuntu linux path:
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/html/package.json

Answer (score -1):

Jesse's answer is correct. I don't have enough reputation points to comment on his answer, but the path for Mac users is:

`cd /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/html/`

Note that there will already be some extensions so instead of copying and pasting the code snippets wholesale, simply add the extension you'd like to the extensions and aliases array like so:

```
{
    "name": "html",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "publisher": "vscode",
    "engines": { "vscode": "*" },
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [{
            "id": "html",
            "extensions": [ ".html", ".htm", ".shtml", ".mdoc", ".jsp", ".asp", ".aspx", ".jshtm", ".ejs" ],
            "aliases": [ "HTML", "htm", "html", "xhtml", "ejs" ],
            "mimetypes": ["text/html", "text/x-jshtm", "text/template", "text/ng-template"]
        }],
        "grammars": [{
            /* "language": "html", not yet enabled*/
            "scopeName": "text.html.basic",
            "path": "./syntaxes/HTML.plist"
        }]
    },
    "extensionDependencies": [
                "html"
    ]
}
```