# Is there a smarty tpl code formatter for visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, smarty, code-formatting

I am using Smarty as Template-Engine for PHP. My IDE is Visual Studio Community 2017. I'm searching for a code formatter, which supports smarty tpl files. Maybe it is also possible to open .tpl files as HTML as for example described here for Visual Studio Code: [Visual Studio Code: Treat other extensions as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656126/visual-studio-code-treat-other-extensions-as-html)? I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can transform your tpl file in .html file. Doesn't matter if it's .tpl or .html.